# Does my use case diagram need something more?

Tags: uml, use-case-diagram

I have a task to make a simple information system for the functioning of a guest house. I need to make a USE CASE diagram, but I don't know if what I've done is correct, or if I need to add something, I don't know where to include the maid.

As users of the system I have put - client, receptionist, manager

As objects of the system I have put client, room, occupied rooms, employees (maids, receptionist, manager), tour agency, payment

Can you give me a hand?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are at the verge of functional decomposition. And that's not what UCs are about. They are about added value. So the bubbles contain headers describing those added values. For a hotel the basic UC would be *Reserve room*. (A real hotel would of course offer more added values, but for your example that's it.)

Now, the reservation is usually going along with payment. But would you consider that added value? I would not. So rather than making these UCs they are constraints (from requirements defined elsewhere). There's a lot one could talk about representing requirements and business rules, but that is far too much for a discussion here. I recommend reading Bittner/Spence about UC sythesis. It takes that book and a lot of experience to get familiar with this area.

Note that UCs are described with subject/predicate(/object) to be meaningful. `Room`  is no UC. If you intend to show an object, use a rectangle (with object notation). That however, is in most times more confusing than helpful. Stay with actors and (real!) use cases.

Another note: the downward association from *Hotel manager* should rather be a generalization (open triangle instead of an arrow). And the actors usually are also shown with arms ;-)